# Rspec can't get controller create action to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd

Been working on writing the correct test all day, but I can't figure it out.

A comment belongs to a user and an outlet
Each outlet has a user
Each out has many comments
Each user has many outlets

At the moment I'm getting this error:

```
Failure/Error: let(:outlet) { FactoryGirl.build(:outlet) }

     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Username has already been taken, Email has already been taken
```

I really don't know what else to try. I've tried switching my factories and tests around a bunch, but only got different errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :comment do
    body "This is a comment"
    user
    outlet
  end

  factory :invalid_comment, class: Comment do
    body "This is a comment"
    user nil
    outlet nil
  end  
end
```

---

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :outlet do
    category "vent"
    title "MyString"
    body "MyText"
    urgency 1
    user
  end

  factory :invalid_outlet, class: Outlet do
    category "qualm"
    title ""
    body ""
    urgency 3
    user factory: :user
  end
end
```

---

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do
        sequence(:username) { |n| "test_user#{n}" }
        sequence(:email)    { |n| "test_user#{n}@email.com" }
        password "password"
    end

    factory :invalid_user, class: User do
        username ""
        email ""
        password ""
    end
end
```

Test

```
describe 'create' do
        context 'with valid attributes' do
            let(:outlet) { FactoryGirl.create(:outlet) }            
            let(:comment_params) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:comment) }
            let(:create) { post :create, params: { id: outlet , comment: comment_params } }

            it "creates new comment" do
                puts outlet
                puts comment_params
                expect { create }.to change { Comment.count }.by 1
            end
        end
    end
```

---

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @comment = Comment.new
    end

    def create
        @outlet = Outlet.find(params[:id])
        @comment = @outlet.comments.build(comment_params)

        if @comment.save
            redirect_to(@outlet)
        end
    end


    private
    def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :outlet_id, :user_id)
    end
end
```

Comment: You're saying the error is caused by `FactoryGirl.build(:outlet)` yet that doesn't appear anywhere in your code. Is this all up to date?

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that your generated username/emails are colliding with names in the database.  That might happen if you have username created from one run still in your database on a later run.

If you are are not already using it, consider adding the [`DatabaseCleaner` gem](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner) to your project. It provides various ways to ensure your database is reset between runs.